# X-axis decimal "," instead of "."

Tags: pgfplots, punctuation

i have little problem.
Have this bar chart 
[image: bar chart]
                                                                                   made by this code

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}     
   \begin{axis}[              
        width=5in,
         nodes near coords,
        height=1.4in,    
        y grid style = empty,      
        extra y tick style={grid=none},           
        at={(0.758in,0.981in)},
        scale only axis,
        clip=false,        
        axis on top,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=5,
        xtick={1,2,3,4},           
        xticklabels={0.00-0.20,0.21-1.00,1.00-2.00,více},
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=8,
        ylabel={},
        every axis plot/.append style={
          ybar,
          bar width=0.8cm,
          bar shift=0pt,
          fill
        }
      ]

      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(1,1)};
      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(2,2)};
      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(3,2)};
      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(4,1)};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Honestly i feel ashamed for this, because i know just few command, cause i´ve just copied it from another "question" topic...
But i would like to have

> 0,00-0,20 instead of 0.00-0.20

I found some code here like

```
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      use comma,
      1000 sep={}]
     \addplot +[domain=0:1] {(x+rnd)*4000};
```

But it doesn´t solve it in my case.

I would be glad for every advice, thank you all.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! in future, please always instead of code snippet provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. with this you will help us to help you!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        width=5in,
         nodes near coords,
        height=1.4in,
        y grid style = empty,
        extra y tick style={grid=none},
        at={(0.758in,0.981in)},
        scale only axis,
        clip=false,
        axis on top,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=5,
        xtick={1,2,3,4},
        xticklabels={{0,00-0,20},{0,21-1,00},{1,00-2,00},více},% <------
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=8,
        ylabel={},
        every axis plot/.append style={
          ybar,
          bar width=0.8cm,
          bar shift=0pt,
          fill
        }
      ]

      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(1,1)};
      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(2,2)};
      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(3,2)};
      \addplot[blue]coordinates{(4,1)};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I would like to give you +1, but i can´t :(

Comment: I should add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to your code for the word _více_ to have the accent.

Comment: @kores59 but you can accept the answer instead. Click on the check mark below vote counter.